# Turn SQL Query Into Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a SQL query that, for the most part, will return the location of a string, wherever it occurs in a given database.

I'd like to turn this into a function in SQL, but I don't have enough experience (read: Any experience) with functions and am having trouble doing so.

```
    /* Set @SearchStr to a string you are looking for and all text columns of a DB
   will be searched to find that string */

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = 'TYPE What you are looking for here'

DECLARE @Results TABLE (
      TableName nvarchar(256)
    , ColumnName nvarchar(370)
    , ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)
    )

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
  , @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
  , @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = (SELECT    MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                          FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                          WHERE     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)),
                                                       'IsMSShipped') = 0)

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
            AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @ColumnName = (SELECT   MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                                   FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                   WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                                            AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                                            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)

                IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @sql = 'SELECT TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName
                            + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + 'WHERE ' + @ColumnName
                            + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                        --PRINT @sql
                        INSERT  INTO @Results
                                EXECUTE (@sql
                                       )
                    END
            END 
    END

SELECT * FROM @Results
```

I've attempted to turn this into a 'create function' statement, but I always get a syntax error somewhere.

This is the farthest i've gotten with this, and my execution of this SQL will give me the error message "Invalid syntax near 'Return'" :

```
create function dbo.FindString( @SearchStr Varchar(256) )

RETURNS
@Results TABLE (
      TableName nvarchar(256)
    , ColumnName nvarchar(370)
    , ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)
    )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
--DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = ''


SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
  , @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
  , @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = (SELECT    MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                          FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                          WHERE     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)),
                                                       'IsMSShipped') = 0)

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
            AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @ColumnName = (SELECT   MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                                   FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                   WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                                            AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                                            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)

                IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @sql = 'SELECT TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName
                            + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + 'WHERE ' + @ColumnName
                            + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                        --PRINT @sql
                        INSERT  INTO @Results
                                EXECUTE (@sql
                                       )
                    END
            END 

    END

Return
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: ^ A note - this is a SQL string that I pawned off of a coworker, who found it god knows where on the internet. So if I'm not crediting the source of this SQL, which I definitely have not accomplished on my own, that would be why.

Comment: I don't think you can use dynamic SQL inside a function.

Comment: You can't use `set nocount on` either.

Comment: I think the only part you're missing is an `end` at the end.

Comment: @shawnt00 I included an 'END' at the end, and received the following errors:
Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure FindString, Line 17
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET OPTION ON' within a function.
Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure FindString, Line 52
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Comment: Yeah, I already commented on those a bit ago. But as for the function syntax you only needed the `end`. It's a small consolation that you were close at least.

Comment: Oh, understood. That made me laugh :) Do you know of a way that I could achieve similar functionality within a function? I'm quite perplexed.

Comment: Why do you need a function? Is a stored procedure good enough?

Comment: I believe a stored procedure would be fine as long as it returned the same results. Any end result that doesn't require me to copy / paste in this massive query when I need to use it is a good result to me :)

Comment: However - I don't know how to turn this into a stored precedure, either...

Comment: Change `function` to `procedure`. Get rid of the whole `returns...as` keep the `as`. Change `return` to `select * from @Results`. And get rid of the parentheses around the argument list.

Comment: To run it you say `exec dbo.FindString 'test';` And put a `GO` on its own line after the final `end` just to make sure you separate it from any commands you add later.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks! Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Ok ;) I guess I might as well finish the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step syntactically is just to add an `end` as the final line of the script to pair up with the first `begin`. Unfortunately at that point you'll get complaints about using `set nocount on` and `exec` inside a function. The first of those is no sweat but the second one is a problem.

Since you can't use dynamic sql inside functions your next best option is a stored procedure and only minor surgery is required here. Step one is to change the definition to a procedure, starting off with the line below replacing everything up to the initial `as` and including the entire `returns @results` section.

```
create procedure dbo.FindString @SearchStr Varchar(256) as
```

The last tweak is to change `return` to a `select * from @Results`.

Make sure to add `go` on separate lines before and after when using this as part of a longer script. `create procedure` must appear as it's own separate batch. Use `exec dbo.FindString 'test'` to try it out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

The SQL to create this stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.FindString( @SearchStr Varchar(256) )

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
--DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
--SET @SearchStr = ''

DECLARE @Results TABLE (
      TableName nvarchar(256)
    , ColumnName nvarchar(370)
    , ColumnValue nvarchar(3630)
    )

--SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
  , @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
  , @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = (SELECT    MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                          FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                          WHERE     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)),
                                                       'IsMSShipped') = 0)

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
            AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                SET @ColumnName = (SELECT   MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                                   FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                   WHERE    TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                                            AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                                            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)

                IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @sql = 'SELECT TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName
                            + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + 'WHERE ' + @ColumnName
                            + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                        --PRINT @sql
                        INSERT  INTO @Results
                                EXECUTE (@sql
                                       )
                    END
            END 

    END

SELECT * FROM @Results


END
```